# Action bar menu not updating properly after adding new items

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I originally had a menu that looked like:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

The app was published. I then added in another Item, so it now looks like this:

```
  Line1
  Line2
  Line4 << newly added item
  Line3
```

I updated all my code and it works, but with some added side effects. The original "Line3" was pulling up a app list to share 'something'. Line 4 was added in to open another specific app. What happens now is if I click on Line4, the app opens and all is well until I hit the back button to go back to the original app, I see that the app list for sharing 'Something' opened up as well, meaning I have to click the back button twice.

This is my code (representing the second example above)

```
/**creates action bar**/
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   /**handles which action item is selected**/
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle presses on the action bar items
       switch (item.getItemId()) {

           case R.id.stuff:
               startActivity(new                        Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
               return true;

           case R.id.MoreStuff:
              //things
               return true;

           case R.id.TheProblemStuff:
               Intent intent1 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("anApp");
               if (intent1 != null)
               {
                   /* we found the activity now start the activity */
                   intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   startActivity(intent1);
               }
               else
               {
                   /* bring user to the market or let them choose an app? */
                   intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   intent.setData(Uri.parse("a website .com"));
                   startActivity(intent);
               }


           case R.id.TheOtherProblemStuff:
               Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Check out this app!");
               sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
               sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,("myapp"));
               startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share using"));//this is the menu that still comes up when "TheProblemStuff" is clicked. This use to be in the spot that "TheProblemStuff" was
               return true;

           default:
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   }
```

and here is my xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.gpstest1.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Stuff"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/MoreStuff"
        android:title="@string/action_map"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/TheProblemStuff"
        android:title="@string/speedometer"
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item 
        android:id="@+id/TheOtherProblemStuff"
        android:title="@string/action_share_app"
        android:orderInCategory="4"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot the `return true;` line inside the `R.id.TheProblemStuff:` case, so it continues to the `R.id.TheOtherProblemStuff` case and only then stops.